# How to redirect and pass data as props on form submit in React?

Tags: reactjs, react-router-dom, react-router-v4

I have a functional component as so:

```
const SearchForm = () => {
    //stuffs

    const handleSubmit = e => {
        e.preventDefault();
        fetchData();
        return <Redirect to='/search' data={fetchedData} />
    }


    return (
        <div>
            <form onSubmit={ handleSubmit }>
                <div className='input-field'>
                <input placeholder="Search whatever you wish" 
                    type="text"
                    value={keyword}
                    onChange={(e) => setKeyword(e.target.value)}
                    className='searchfield center-align white-text'
                />
                </div>
            </form>
        </div>
    )
}

export default SearchForm;
```

After the form is submitted, I want the page to be redirected to `/search`, and I want the `fetchedData` to be passed along with it. I tried using the `Redirect` component from `react-router-dom` but it doesn't seem to work. Any fix?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you can do from two ways

1.

```
  const SearchForm = () => {
        //stuffs

        const [redirect, setRedirect] = useState(false);
        const [data, setData] = useState();

        const handleSubmit = e => {
            e.preventDefault();
            fetchData();
            setRedirect(true);
            setData(e);
        }
        if (redirect)
            return <Redirect to={{ pathname: '/search', data: { data } }} />

        return (
            <div>
                <form onSubmit={handleSubmit}>
                    <div className='input-field'>
                        <input placeholder="Search whatever you wish"
                            type="text"
                            value={keyword}
                            onChange={(e) => setKeyword(e.target.value)}
                            className='searchfield center-align white-text'
                        />
                    </div>
                </form>
            </div>
        )
    }

    export default SearchForm;
```

2.

```
const SearchForm = (props) => {
    //stuffs

    const [redirect, setRedirect] = useState(false);
    const [data, setData] = useState();

    const handleSubmit = e => {
        e.preventDefault();
        fetchData();
        props.history.push({
            pathname: '/search',
            state:
            {
                //your data
            }
        })
    }

    return (
        <div>
            <form onSubmit={handleSubmit}>
                <div className='input-field'>
                    <input placeholder="Search whatever you wish"
                        type="text"
                        value={keyword}
                        onChange={(e) => setKeyword(e.target.value)}
                        className='searchfield center-align white-text'
                    />
                </div>
            </form>
        </div>
    )
}

export default SearchForm;
```

Comment: @iscream if this does ans to your que than please consider as a marked.

Comment: happy to help :)

Answer (score 1):

this is how to do it by passing `state` object in `to` prop:

```
<Redirect
  to={{
    pathname: "/search",
    state: { data:fetchedData}
  }}
/>
```

Answer (score 1):

You can not use the `<Redirect />` component in your fallback function because it's a component and can not be rendered there.
If you are using `react-router-dom`, you can easily use its hooks to redirect the user to another route. Using hooks are simpler and keeps your components easy to read.

Try this:

```
import { useHistory } from "react-router-dom";

const SearchForm = () => {
    const { push } = useHistory();
    //stuffs

    const handleSubmit = e => {
        e.preventDefault();
        fetchData();
        push({
            pathname: '/search',
            state: {
                data: fetchedData
            }
        })
    }


    return (
        <div>
            <form onSubmit={handleSubmit}>
                <div className='input-field'>
                    <input placeholder="Search whatever you wish"
                        type="text"
                        value={keyword}
                        onChange={(e) => setKeyword(e.target.value)}
                        className='searchfield center-align white-text'
                    />
                </div>
            </form>
        </div>
    )
}
```